# Newlines not preserved when copying / pasting from Apache Zeppelin

Tags: pandas, vim, newline, apache-zeppelin

I'm printing CSVs in Zeppelin (MacOS 10.14.6, Google Chrome, pyspark, Python 3.6.8) using the pandas `to_csv()` function, and when I copy and paste the results to another application (e.g. Excel, Google Sheets, Apple Notes), it all appears on a single line. I've tried updating the newline character using `to_csv(line_terminator='\r\n')` (for example), but nothing I've tried there has worked either.

However, the newlines *are* preserved when I copy and paste the results into VIM. To figure out what newline character was there, I ran VIM with `-b` and used `:set list` – all I see are `$`s at the end of every line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please share what you have done so far.

Comment: I updated the newline character using `line_terminator='\r\n'` and also tried `'\n'`. I also tried to determine what newline character was actually being used by exposing those characters in VIM, but the output didn't lead to any further insights to me. I'm now stumped about how to proceed.

Comment: what os you are in and what is the version of python.

Comment: MacOS 10.14.6, Python 3.6.8. I've updated the question, thanks for asking.

Comment: you can try the "to_excel" function and see what will happen

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
with open(file_path, mode='w', newline='\r\n') as f:
    data_frame.to_csv(f, index=False)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Hi Chandan, thanks for the answer. While writing to a file might partially solve the problem, my question is actually asking why output from Zeppelin can't be copied and pasted while retaining the newlines. The goal is to quickly copy and paste outputs from Zeppelin to another application, and having to write a new file for every piece of output kind of nukes the "quickly" part of my goal. Thanks!